# VHDL Error when converting std_logic_vector into unsigned integer

Tags: vhdl

I want to convert a 16-bit std_logic_vector into an integer to use it in a process realising a Moore machine.

```
entity steuerung is
  port (
    Clk            : in std_logic;
    Reset           : in std_logic;
    AktPos          : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    Notaus          : in std_logic; 
    Betrieb         : in std_logic; 
    HPR             : in std_logic;   
    HPL             : in std_logic;
    ESR             : in std_logic;
    ESL             : in std_logic;
    CntClr          : out std_logic;
    LedR            : out std_logic;    
    LedG            : out std_logic;        
    M_An            : out std_logic;
    M_Li            : out std_logic;
    M_Re            : out std_logic;
    State           : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)  
  );
end steuerung;

architecture BEHAVE of steuerung is
begin
  process (Reset, Clk, Notaus, Betrieb, AktPos, ESR, ESL) is
    type zustand is (steht, links, rechts, neuUnten, neuOben, alarm);

    variable zustands_vektor : zustand;
    variable ausgabe_vektor  : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    variable cnt             : integer range 0 to 65535 := conv_integer(unsigned(AktPos));
```

But I'm getting a few errors concerning the last line of code.
The console tells me the following:

"no declaration for "unsigned"
 no overloaded function found matching 'conv_integer'"
and also a few errors in the `std_logic_arith` library (which I definitely included, although not seen in the code)

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your question has many issues ... Here is a list of things to fix:

- Use English identifiers for documentation reasons, so others then natives like me can read and understand your question and your code. Moreover you are mixing Germany and English identifiers in the same file.
- Add the full code, so we can see the surrounding context. It's needed to investigate and explain your mistakes.
- `std_logic_arith` is a *package*, not a *library*. `IEEE` would be a VHDL *library*.
- Don't use package `std_logic_arith`. use package `numeric_std` instead.
- When using package `numeric_std`, an `unsigned` value is converted to integer with `to_integer`:
  `cnt := to_integer(unsigned(AktPos));`
- The signals: `Reset`, `Notaus`, `Betrieb`, `AktPos`, `ESR`, and `ESL` don't belong to the sensitivity list of a clocked process.
- The initial value assignment for your variable is executed only once. Probably, this isn't what you want to achieve, right?
- Type `zustand` is an enumeration type. Thus, the variable `zustands_vektor` uses wrong naming for an object containing a scalar discrete value. A vector is an array.

In general, using variables in VHDL is nothing for starters. Most likely, you want to use signals. VHDL is a hardware description language not a programming language, where you use variables for daily problem solving.

Comment: I'm using german names because they were given in the code beforehand, since this is an assignment for university. My professor wrote the entity and the general structure of the whole behaviour file and I was obligated to program the behaviour itself.
However, here is the full code for the file: [link](https://pastebin.com/PEMv5jY3)

I appreciate that you talked about all of the things I'm doing generally wrong, but in this case I only need help for these errors, since the rest of the code is working just fine.

Comment: The solution is to use the mentioned `numeric_std` package and function `to_integer`. Welche Uni oder FH in DE unterrichtet so fehlerhaftes VHDL? Ich beziehe mich hier auf die nicht Standard konformen Packages. Ich kann nur anraten, dass dein Professor mal den IEEE Standard 1076-2008 liest oder von mir Nachhilfe bekommt :) [Short Bio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3719459/paebbels?tab=profile)

Comment: Is the file you linked all written by your professor? Anyway, the linked code can never be synthesized. It contains other big mistakes...

Comment: No, only the entity is written by the professor. Everything included in the architechture is written by me.
Anyways, before I started this topic, I also found the solution with the numeric_std package, but using it gave me the same errors, just with the function "to_integer" instead of "conv_integer".
We're using Vivado for coding, but since my university can't buy every student a Vivado license, the simulation and synthesiting is realized through an external tool.

Comment: Also I made it work when I just used "AktPos" and the binary numbers in the if-statements instead of the cnt-integer. But still, I want to use the integer, where I still run into this problem.

Comment: Vivado is free (webpack license). It is included in all downloads. It includes synthesis for selected chips (Spartan-7, Artix-7) and a free simulator (xSim). Using type `integer` is something I would not recommend, because it is limited to 32 bit signed or 31 bit unsigned binary values. You should use type `unsigned` for your counter. This type is defined in `numeric_std`.

Comment: I know that the functions that we need for university are not included in the free version, which is why we're using external tools for that, but that's not the problem here.
My counter only counts from 0 to 65535, so 31-bit unsigned is enough. And as I said, even when using the numeric_std package, the same error occurs.